# Adsense API live reporting

Tags: adsense-api

I want to integrate my Adsense Reporting into my own admin portal. 
My admin portal is a simple php based website with lists of other websites that I own. 
My goal is to fill this list of websites with the amount of earnings monthly.

So that this list looks like:

```
name       | earnings
example.de | 56,00€
```

The whole week I am trying to start with the Google API but without any success.

Does anybody know how to get this information live? for example with google apis link?

Answer (score 9):

AdSense **Management** API is what you want, for reporting.

You'll need client library:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation

And you'll probably want to browse the `example` folder here:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/php-clientlib-1.x/v1.x

Then, get the API key so you can start playing:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/api-keys
https://console.developers.google.com/
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20199357/246808

**EDIT**: Almost forgot - the manual:
https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/getting_started

Comment: Hello. I have installed the client library and have copied the examples tree but I cannot find Google/Client.php & Google/Service/AdSense.php in these. Any idea where I can find them ?